# Joining street ID to Sidewalk polygons using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, attribute-joins, spatial-join, streets

I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.0.3.

I am trying to match a set of Street IDs (line data) to sidewalk polygons. I have buffered the street line data based on street width, and then ran a spatial join, joining the closest Street ID within a 50 ft search radius to each sidewalk polygon. However, the results are not always reliable as sidewalks polygons are often set far from street buffers, and many of my street buffers are not aligning well with the sidewalk polygons (issues are shown below). **Given the issues I've outlined, what are other possible methods (or improvements on my current method) for joining Street ID to sidewalk polygons?**

In image 1, sidewalk polygons (pink polygons) are set far back from the street buffer (blue buffer) at the end of the cul de sacs pictured below. Results in the sidewalks polygons at the end of the cul de sac being matched to the Street ID 5713000, which is incorrect.

[image: Image 1]

In image 2, my street line data is not always aligning well with my sidewalk polygons.

[image: Image 2]

Comment: you can use the sidewalk polygon centroid to find the nearest street. But from the 1st picture, the 4 polygons on each side of the street intersections don't belong to a single street.

Comment: For the 2nd picture, garbage in - garbage out. I would find a way to fix the data first.